# Two Elasticbeanstalk instances in the same environment both were told they were the "leader" ... how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have something like the following, somewhere like .ebextensions/some.config

```
container_commands:
  01-command:
    command: echo "export ELASTICBEANSTALK_LEADER=true" >> /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
    leader_only: true
```

I am staring in abject horror at two instances in the same environment which both have that environment variable set, wondering how that is possible... I may misunderstand something about how container_commands get executed or how beanstalk adds/removes instances. I was under the impression that with the above container_commands config, there would never be more than one instance with that environment variable set. I am sure that nothing else in my code sets it.

Of possible significance, I suppose, is the fact that I recently changed the beanstalk environment configuration to increase the min-instances.

I understand that which instance is the leader can change during deploys, I haven't been able to find anything very specific about the details of this, in AWS docs or from the community. Specifically, I am wondering if it can change such that a new instance being added becomes the leader, and another instance which was previously the leader is not stopped? That seems very odd, but it is the only theory I've come up with so far. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: Beanstalk is a poisonous monster